# APIM requests weight policy

Tags: apim

Computing cost of each APIs are different (some GET methods is more lightweight than POST for e.g.).
To achieve flexible and fair distribution of API usages for each users/tenants, we'd like to set weights to each API calls, and ratelimit or set quota on total weights requested.

For example, in Apigee platform, you can configure message weight for each apis.

Is it possible to achieve such by utilizing APIM policies?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)